# Using Array vs. Hash vs. Set?

Tags: ruby, hash, set

I want to create a "process" object, with a few different fields, which is identified by a unique process ID.  I need to be able to create a variable number of instances of these objects, update fields in a specific object and remove the object instance when I am done with it, while keeping other instances of the object.  I anticipate less than 5000 instances of the process object at any one time.

I read about Arrays and Hashes and Sets and I am not sure what object would be best to track the multiple occurrences of my process objects and make it efficient to find the correct instance of a particular process object for updating or removal.

I keep thinking of using a Hash for the process ID but the Hash class has a value and I do not think my process object is a value.

I will keep researching but a shove in the right direction would be appreciated,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are neat methods called Process#pid and Thread::list: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Process.html#method-c-pid http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html#method-c-list

Comment: Each member of a hash has a key and a value.  In your application, as you suggest, the key would be the process ID.  Perhaps you misunderstand what "value" means in this context.  It is any Ruby object, which can be a literal, such as 7 or :cat, or something as complex as, say, an array of hashes whose keys are strings and values are methods.

Comment: Think of a Set is a Hash without values, only keys. In practice Set has more Array-like behaviors than a Hash. For a process table I'd probably use a Hash because it's basically random-access, so it's fastest. Adding and deleting elements is easy with normal hash assignments and using [`delete`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete).

Comment: Cary, you are right, it was not clear to me in this case what a 'value' was and not sure that a value could be an object rather than a single variable or literal (and didn't find any examples showing this.)  The hash I think will do the ticket - processID for the hash key and the entire instance of the object as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I keep thinking hash for the process ID but the hash class has a value and I do not think my process object is a value?

You can store anything in a Ruby Hash.

This makes the hash a fantastic method for storing the info.